# How do I send an email through UNIX sendmail command?

Tags: email, unix

I want to execute sendmail command from a shell script file. Content of the email is in a text file.

Syntax to use mail command is:
/bin/mail -s MailSubject abc.pqr@xyz.com < mail_content.txt

Syntax to use sendmail is:
echo "Subject: MailSubject" | cat - mail_content.txt | /usr/bin/sendmail abc.pqr@xyz.com

Can you please let me know how I could use sendmail using a syntax which is similar to that of mail command, without using echo command and by specifying subject, to address and mail content file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use sendmail as below

```
sendmail abc.pqr@xyz.com <mail_content.txt
```

Subject of the mail should be in mail_content.txt starting with `Subject :`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Is there any other way I could include subject to the command without updating the mail content file? I don't have access to modify the file. Can you please let me know if any other approach is possible?

Comment: the only other way is echo and pipe (echo "Subject:sub" | sendmail